# Tortoise-ORM: поля связанных объектов в __str__

Tags: python, orm, asyncio, aiohttp

Я разрабатываю сервис АПИ используя AIOHTTP, пытаюсь прикрутить какую-нибудь асинхронную ORM, выбор пал на Tortoise-ORM (следующий кандидат Gino). На данный момент возник такой вопрос.

В Django проекте у меня есть много связанных моделей с методами `__str__`, выглядит это примерно так:

```py
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import fields

class Department(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    title = fields.TextField()
    upper = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Department', related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        if self.upper is not None:
            return f'{self.id} Department {self.title} of {self.upper.title}'
        else:
            return f'{self.id} Department {self.title}, head'

class Employee(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.TextField()
    dep = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Department', related_name='employees')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}. Employee {self.name} of {self.dep.title}'
```

Так что каждый объект ссылается на многие другие и показывает их в своём описании. Но Tortoise при этом выдаёт ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'

Кажется, сделать await внутри метода `__str__` не получится. Можно ли вообще использовать поля связанных моделей для построения такого описания объекта в Tortoise-ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tortoise-ORM` не позволяет автоматически извлекать связанные объекты из БД, пока не будет явно выполнен запрос. Обращения к связанным полям возвращают лишь объект `QuerySet` без взаимодействия с БД.

Чтобы получить связанные объекты надо использовать методы `prefetch_related()` или `fetch_related()` перед работой с объектами, после чего соответствующие поля будут возвращать конкретный объект, а не `QuerySet`. [Документация](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html#tortoise.queryset.QuerySet.prefetch_related).

Примеры:

```py
emp_one = await Employee.filter(name="Emp_1").prefetch_related("dep").first()
print(emp_one)

emp_two = await Employee.filter(name="Emp_2").first()
await emp_two.fetch_related("dep")
print(emp_two)
```

<sub>Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763720/5308802).</sub>